# How do i generalise a polynomial nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im aware that there exists linear nth terms and quadratic nth terms, such as 1,2,3,… and 1,3,6,10,… which can be calculated using the following method…

Lets say we want to find the nth term of a quadratic sequence, well we would substitute values of n={1,2,3,…,n} into an^2+bn+c and we have…

a+b+c,4a+2b+c,9a+3b+c,…

3 terms is enough since we only need (degree of polynomial) +1 terms to calcualte the nth term. After finding the 1st and 2nd differences we can compair coefficients with our original sequence and obtain the nth term of the from an^2+bn+c where we solve for a,b and c. Ive done this method for cubic, quartic and quintic polynomials, but i want to generalise the mth degree polynomial nth term (what i mean by that is if a sequance’s nth term is of the form an^m+bn^(m-1)+…+1 then its the mth degree polynomial nth term).

This method is really long for higher degree polynomials, is there a quiker and more general way of computing the nth term for these polyonomials?

The reason i ask, is because the following 4 sereies:

q=1,2,3,4,… (linear nth term)(k=1)
W=,1,3,6,10(quadratic nth term)(k=2)
E=1,4,10,20,… (cubic nth term)(k=3)
R=1,5,15,35,… (quartic nth term)(k=4)

Are each linear, quadratic, cubic, quartic nth term sequances respectively, and if you see closer the n-k+1 th term of a sequance (where k is the value of the degree of the nth term) is the value of nCk=n!/k!(n-k)!. I have found a systen to generate these sequences such that they give values of nCk yet i cant generalise the polynomial nth term because everytime i have a new squence i have to do it by hand, so is there a method to find the nth term in a more general way rather then algbreaically comparing coefficients.

The only progress ive made was that the denominator of the nth term is k! Where the coefficients of the terms of the numerator are intigers e.g for the sequence 1,3,6,10,… (k=2 for this sequence) the nth term is (n^2+n)/2!
And at first assumed summations may be solution but as i work with larger polynomial nth terms the relashionship between each nth term fades.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton's_series

Comment: Not exactly but it seems like it helps with my specific problem, to be honest im not sure if an answere to my orignial ask exists, so thanks